# A noun: the tool to fix neck in the neck sprain treatment

Tags: nouns, terminology, generic-term

What is the tool to fix one's neck in a neck sprain treatment?

It could be soft or hard, in plastic.

I did a web search for neck fixture, but it turned out to be a component of a lamp.

Comment: i think SrJoven has the right answer, but a neck brace or cervical collar is not usually called a "tool" or a "fixture", but rather a "medical appliance".  Since you asked for a tool to fix a neck sprain, one could take that in the same sense as a tool to fix your car's engine.  Yes, "fix" can mean hold in place, but it is ambiguous. I think your question would be better worded as "a device to hold neck steady" rather "tool to fix neck". May I edit it that way? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably called a [neck brace](https://www.google.com/search?q=neck+brace) or cervical collar.